# How could we assign constraits values in our matlab simulation?

Tags: python, matlab, gekko

This example was used as a case study to develop a predictive control model to maintain optimal airspeed and climb rate values by adjusting the thrust of the motors and elevator of a Boeing-747 that is flying at 40000 feet. Given that the outputs (airspeed and climb rate) are considered as deviation variables and therefore evaluated as variations with respect to nominal reference values, rather than in absolute terms, the same must be done even when assigning values to constraints that refer to the input (thrust and elevator). In this regard, how would it be possible to assign output-consistent values to our constraints in our Matlab simulation? Which could be their upper and lower bounds?

Here is the [case study with Matlab and Python code](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ModelSimulation).

[image: airplane]

Here is sample Gekko code:

[image: results]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

## Linear model of a Boeing 747
#  Level flight at 40,000 ft elevation
#  Velocity at 774 ft/sec (0.80 Mach)

# States
#  u - uw (ft/sec) - horizontal velocity - horizontal wind
#  w - ww (ft/sec) - vertical velocity - vertical wind
#  q (crad/sec) - angular velocity
#  theta (crad) - angle from horizontal
# note: crad = 0.01 rad

# Inputs
#  e - elevator
#  t - throttle

# Outputs
#  u - uw (ft/sec) - horizontal airspeed
#  hdot = -w + u0 * theta with u0 = 774 ft/sec


A = np.array([[-.003, 0.039, 0, -0.322],
              [-0.065, -0.319, 7.74, 0],
              [0.020, -0.101, -0.429, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0]])

B = np.array([[0.01, 1],
              [-0.18, -0.04],
              [-1.16, 0.598],
              [0, 0]])

C = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, -1, 0, 7.74]])

#%% Build GEKKO State Space model
m = GEKKO()
x,y,u = m.state_space(A,B,C,D=None)

m.time = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 15]
m.options.imode = 6
m.options.nodes = 3

## MV tuning
# lower and upper bounds for elevator pitch
# lower and upper bounds for thrust
# delta MV movement cost
for i in range(len(u)):
    u[i].lower = -5
    u[i].upper = 5
    u[i].dcost = 1
    u[i].status = 1

## CV tuning
# tau = first order time constant for trajectories
y[0].tau = 5
y[1].tau = 8
# tr_init = 0 (dead-band)
#         = 1 (first order trajectory)
#         = 2 (first order traj, re-center with each cycle)
y[0].tr_init = 2
y[1].tr_init = 2
# targets (dead-band needs upper and lower values)
# SPHI = upper set point
# SPLO = lower set point
y[0].sphi= -8.5
y[0].splo= -9.5
y[1].sphi= 5.4
y[1].splo= 4.6

y[0].status = 1
y[1].status = 1


m.solve()

# get additional solution information (trajectories)
import json
with open(m.path+'//results.json') as f:
    results = json.load(f)
# get internal GEKKO variable names
air_speed = y[0].name
climb_rate = y[1].name

#%% plot results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(311)
plt.plot(m.time,u[0],'b-',lw=2.0)
plt.plot(m.time,u[1],'g:',lw=2.0)
plt.legend(['Elevator','Thrust'])
plt.ylabel('MV Action')

plt.subplot(312)
plt.plot(m.time,y[0],'r-',lw=2.0)
plt.plot(m.time,results[air_speed+'.tr_hi'],'k:')
plt.plot(m.time,results[air_speed+'.tr_lo'],'k:')
plt.legend(['Air Speed','Upper Trajectory','Lower Trajectory'])
plt.ylabel('Air Speed')

plt.subplot(313)
plt.plot(m.time,y[1],'r-',lw=2.0)
plt.plot(m.time,results[climb_rate+'.tr_hi'],'k:')
plt.plot(m.time,results[climb_rate+'.tr_lo'],'k:')
plt.legend(['Climb Rate','Upper Trajectory','Lower Trajectory'])
plt.ylabel('Climb Rate')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I've added additional context to the question to give additional background for the problem. Andrea - please clarify if additional information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

State space models are typically in [deviation variable form](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/StateSpaceModel) so state constraints need to account for the offset when setting constraints. There are nominal values for the controlled variable: air speed `y1` as 744ft/sec or 816km/hr and climb rate `y2` as 0. A simple way to fix this is to include the offset when setting the target values in Matlab:

**Original**

```matlab
apm_option(s,a,'y[1].sphi',-8.5);
apm_option(s,a,'y[1].splo',-9.5);
apm_option(s,a,'y[2].sphi',5.4);
apm_option(s,a,'y[2].splo',4.6);
```

**Modified**

```matlab
y1_offset = 744;
apm_option(s,a,'y[1].sphi',735.5 - y1_offset);
apm_option(s,a,'y[1].splo',734.4 - y1_offset);
y2_offset = 0;
apm_option(s,a,'y[2].sphi',5.4 - y2_offset);
apm_option(s,a,'y[2].splo',4.6 - y2_offset);
```

If you want to include select state variables as constraint then augment the `C` matrix to include another output variable and include a hard or soft constraint on that output.

[image: state space model]